# Plugin recommendation - StackExchange style Q&A

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Happy to spend a bit of money to get this right.

I'm looking for a comprehensive Q&A plugin which has the following features:

- Can be used with my very customised theme
- Ability to ask questions
- Ability to post answers
- Ability to ask comments on both questions and answers
- Reputation and voting system, similar to WPSE etc.
- Ability to attach images in questions and answers
- Rich text editor (preferably `wp_editor` style but I'll put up with something else if I have to). Italic text is *mandatory* for writing scientific names.

I'd also *like* the following:

- Badges which I can rename/add descriptions to
- Bounties

I paid a fair amount of money for the [Q&A Plugin subscription](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin-lite) and it was hopeless. Looks good on the outside, but no comments or media attachment which makes the system useless in my eyes. Nor does it have anything above reputation for engagement.

I know there have been other Questions on this subject and I've looked into those, but I have quite specific requirements where the others appear not to.

I've seen [AskIt](http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/AskIt/) which appears not to have a rich text editor or the facility to attach media. I've also seen [Sofa Q&A](http://themeforest.net/item/sofa-qanda-knowledge-base-wp-theme/180802) which appears to be an entire theme rather than just a plugin, though I have asked the author if it would work with my site.

Does anyone have any other suggestions? There must be something out there!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the best plugin out there for Q&A type of site is [Q&A](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin) by WPMUDEV which also come in a [free lite version](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qa/) if you want to test it out first and answers all of your requirements.

Comment: Hi Bainternet. I discussed that plugin in my original post - it has no comments nor media attachment, which are a prerequisite for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yeah but since both types (questions and answers) support comments you only need to display them and as for  the image upload you simply need to hook your upload button to the tinymce look at http://justboil.me/tinymce-images-plugin/ for ideas

Comment: How would I go about displaying the comments Bain, can you give me an example?

Comment: If Im not wrong then you need to edit the single-question.php template and add your comments using `get_comments` and for answers look for a function named `the_answer_list()`

Comment: the lite version has been removed.