# Q&A lite plugin comments

Tags: plugins, third-party-applications

I am trying out the [Q&A lite plugin from WPMU](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin-lite). It looks great except for one thing. It looks like users can only ask and answer question, not make comments on them. This effectively makes a conversation between two users very short. One question, one answer, that's it, excepting answers from other users of course, but there can be no conversation as such, which I find puzzling as to how effective it could be. Can anyone tell me if I am using it wrong? I think not but if I am I would like to know, otherwise can anyone recommend something similar.

Comment: And how should we take a look at the code? Register » download » inspect? Close vote.

Comment: I just thought some people might have used it that's all. You don't have to register or anything, it's in the repository, so I don't know what the problem is on that front.

Comment: Use dwqa plugin.

Comment: Note, this is a two year old post so I'm not sure the relevancy of any of this new conversation, but thanks anyway ... however I ended up using http://www.question2answer.org/ which while not a WP plugin, is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a [similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42815/plugin-recommendation-stackexchange-style-qa) which received a nice amount of answers and the main issue with the plugin you linked was that it had no comments for the questions and answers and if you look at the comments you will see that both types (questions and answers) support comments you only need to display them.

Answer (score 0):

Questions and answers work as posts, just with 'post_type' 'question' or 'answer'

As they're posts they can have comments. Just work around that.